# Installing GNOME desktop in Kubuntu: getting rid of KDE Wallet Service

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde, services, kwallet

I have Kubuntu 20.10.

Now I wanted the GNOME desktop.

So I installed the package `ubuntu-desktop` and removed all the packages `kde*` and `plasma*`.

I also changed the plymouth theme.

But now eveytime I boot the PC, after login the following windows appears:

[image]

What is the application `-c`?

How can I get rid of KDE Wallet Service and have GNOME manage my wallet instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have run `sudo apt-get remove libkf*` and the message disappeared.